# What is principal value integral?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics

The Fourier transform below gives a delta function

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!dt ~e^{i\omega t}~=~2\pi\delta(\omega).$$

then what is the value if the integral range becomes $t=0\to\infty$?

$$\int_0^\infty \!dt ~e^{i\omega t} ~=~ \text{?}$$

I find it's related to principal value. What is principal value and how to derive the integral?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you are taking the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function.

By definition, we see that
\begin{align}
\langle \hat H, \varphi\rangle :=&\ \langle H, \hat \varphi\rangle = \int^\infty_0 \hat \varphi(\omega)\ d\omega= \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{i\omega t} \varphi(t)\ dt d\omega\\
=&\ \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+}\int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{(it-\alpha) \omega} \varphi(t)\ dt d\omega\\
=&\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0^+} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \left(\int^\infty_0 e^{(it-\alpha)\omega}d\omega\ \right)\varphi(t) dt\\
=&\ \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\varphi(t)}{\alpha-it}dt = \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+t^2}+\frac{it}{\alpha^2+t^2}\right)\varphi(t)\ dt.
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\alpha\varphi(t)}{\alpha^2+t^2}\ dt= \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{\varphi(\alpha u)}{1+u^2}\ du =\varphi(0) \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^2} = \pi\varphi(0) =\langle \pi\delta, \varphi \rangle
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+} i\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{t\varphi(t)}{\alpha^2+t^2}dt =&\ i\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0^+}\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\left(\int^\infty_\varepsilon + \int^{-\varepsilon}_{-\infty} \right)\frac{t\varphi(t)}{\alpha^2+t^2}\ dt\\
=&\ i\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\left(\int^\infty_\varepsilon + \int^{-\varepsilon}_{-\infty} \right)\frac{\varphi(t)}{t}\ dt\\
=&: \langle \text{P.V.}\left(\frac{i}{t}\right), \varphi\rangle.
\end{align}

Since
\begin{align}
\langle \hat H, \varphi\rangle = \langle \pi\delta+\text{P.V.}\left(\frac{i}{t}\right), \varphi\rangle
\end{align}
for any smooth $\varphi$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\hat H = \pi\delta + \text{P.V.}\left(\frac{i}{t}\right).
\end{align}

Just to reiterate. Observe that $\displaystyle \text{P.V.}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ acts on functions in the following manner
\begin{align}
\langle \displaystyle \text{P.V.}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right), \varphi\rangle  = \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\left(\int^\infty_\varepsilon + \int^{-\varepsilon}_{-\infty} \right)\frac{\varphi(t)}{t}\ dt
\end{align}
just like how
\begin{align}
\langle \delta, \varphi\rangle = \varphi(0).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I find the definition of integral of [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is somewhat different. And can we use different definition of the delta function to derive this?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty du/(1 + u^2) = \pi$, giving $\hat H = i t^{-1} + \pi \delta(t)$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake. I will edit it when I am near a computer.